# Track current year and month with a given timestamp

Tags: go

I've a timestamp in the format `181020Z` which is the 18th day of the month, at 1020 UTC.

I'd like to parse this into go whereby `time.Time` gives me `2019-04-18T10:20:00Z` instead of `0000-01-18T10:20:00Z`.

Below is the code I'm using to parse the time

```
    now := time.Now()
    layout := "200601021504Z"
    timeField := strconv.Itoa(now.Year()) + strconv.Itoa(int(now.Month())) + fields[1]
    fmt.Println(timeField) // 20204181050Z
    t, err := time.Parse(layout, timeField)
```

Comment: Prefix the string with the desired year and month and fix layout accordingly. You *have to* tell parse what the year and month is.

Comment: @mkopriva I've updated the code with the latest, but it's still not giving me the right date

Comment: @bear Your updated solution actually works: [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/JZXuA3yXP-P).

Comment: @icza It's not) But only small fix is needed. See my answer

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin No, it's correct. The month in the layout is `01`, not `04`. `04` is for the minutes.

Comment: @icza https://play.golang.org/p/J0p4iv9zFyA. Just try `t, _ := time.Parse(layout, "20204181050Z")`

Comment: @GrigoriyMikhalkin You're right, I though you're saying the format is incorrect. Yes, month have be included with 2 digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach to this:

```
func main()
    now := time.Now()
    layout := "021504Z"

    t, _ := time.Parse(layout, "181020Z")
    t = t.AddDate(now.Year(), int(now.Month()) - 1, 0) 
    fmt.Println(t)  // 2020-04-18T10:20:00Z
```

[Example](https://play.golang.org/p/jmNGrcdmiJ8)

And regarding your last solution -- it's almost correct). Problem is that your layout(`"200601021504Z"`) requires two digit representation of month(i.e. `04` instead of `4` for April). But `now.Month()` returns month representation without `0` padding(i.e. `4`).